# Trying to enter in special characters into an Android text field using adb shell commands

Tags: android, ruby, string, shell, adb

I am trying to enter to special characters into an Android text field, which at the moment, are not working. They are `?` and `|`. I am doing this through some Ruby scripting. So the variable `char` is assigned to the character at hand. Right now I am when I try to enter `?` or `|` nothing shows up. The command right now is `"abd shell \"input text #{char}\""`. For `?`, when it does show it is shows up as a `d`, and `|` does not show up at all. How can I get these characters to work?

Comment: Have you tried with unicode characters?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read "[ask]". Then add a minimal example of your code that demonstrates what you're talking about, and format it for readability. The more research and effort you put into your question, the more interest you'll get from potential answerers resulting to better answers.

Comment: @Mahendran Sakkarai yes, put that in instead of char and it still didn't work.